# May I know what is the font in the github copilot lab video?

Tags: github, fonts, github-copilot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRjIn.jpg)

i want to figure out what is the font in the screenshot, searched and cannot find any clues,

many thanks

i search through the github / google /youtube/ twitter

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.